# Installing compiled python (.pyc) packages from pip to deploy a package

Tags: python, pip, pyc

I am trying to download compiled python packages using pip as `.pyc` files instead of `.py` files to a temporary directory using the `--target` option. I assume by adding the option `--compile` would achieve this but it seems not to work. These packages are listed in a `requirements.txt` file.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

For context, I am trying to deploy a package as a `.zip` file using a script `deploy.py`, and within this script, I add the packages from `requirements.txt` into a temporary directory, which I then add to the zip file through another function `add_to_zip`

Rather than adding `.py` files to this deployed package, I am trying to add `.pyc` files instead.

```
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    subprocess.call([
        'pip', 'install',
        '-r', 'requirements.txt',
        '-t', temp_dir,
        '--compile'
    ])
    add_to_zip(package, temp_dir)
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

When I run this, I get the packages I need, however, all the files are source files `.py` not compiled `.pyc`.

How can I download packages as compiled packages instead of source packages?

Note: am using python3.7

Comment: I did a quick experiment and found that `--compile` is not compatible with `--target`. Perhaps just another bug in `pip`. Please report it at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues. Meanwhile you can use [`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html): something like `subprocess.call(sys.executable, '-m', 'compileall' temp_dir)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go, it looks like a good work around for now